# Transforming a List to a Pivot Table with Python

Tags: python, list, grouping, pivot-table

I have a list of lists in the following format:

```
listA = [[142L, u'Work Load', [57.35, 19.57]],
[142L, u'Days', [84.0, 44.0]],
[142L, u'Payed', [5684.0, 3944.0]],
[547L, u'Work Load', [87.25, 12.70]],
[547L, u'Days', [98.0, 128.0]],
[547L, u'Payed', [3247.0, 4712.0]],
...]
```

and I want to transform it to:

```
listB = [['id', u'Work Load', u'Days', u'Payed'],
[142L, 57.35, 84.0, 5684.0],
[142L, 19.57, 44.0, 3944.0],
[547L, 87.25, 98.0, 3247.0],
[547L, 12.70, 128.0, 4712.0],
...]
```

How can I group them? The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to export the list to csv.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: All elements are ordered by `id`?

Comment: yes but the heders order is not always known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution to my problem:

```
    import pandas as pd
    dt = [[142L, u'Work Load', [57.35, 19.57]],
          [142L, u'Days', [84.0, 44.0]],
          [142L, u'Payed', [5684.0, 3944.0]],
          [547L, u'Work Load', [87.25, 12.70]],
          [547L, u'Days', [98.0, 128.0]],
          [547L, u'Payed', [3247.0, 4712.0]]]
    dfA = pd.DataFrame(dt)
    dfA.columns = [u'id','field','data']
    dfB = dfA.groupby(u'id').apply(
        lambda grp: pd.DataFrame(zip(*grp['data']), columns=grp['field']))
    dfB.index = dfB.index.droplevel(-1)
    data = StringIO()
    dfB.to_csv(data, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
    self.response = HttpResponse(data.getvalue(), mimetype='text/csv')
    self.add_response_headers()
    self.response.close()
    self.response.flush()
    return self.response
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Since the list you showed is sorted by "id", you can use `itertools.groupby` directly and `zip`:

```
In [189]: lst  #if not sorted, lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]) first
Out[189]: 
[[142L, u'Work Load', [57.35, 19.57]],
 [142L, u'Days', [84.0, 44.0]],
 [142L, u'Payed', [5684.0, 3944.0]],
 [547L, u'Work Load', [87.25, 12.7]],
 [547L, u'Days', [98.0, 128.0]],
 [547L, u'Payed', [3247.0, 4712.0]]]

In [190]: lstB=[['id', u'Work Load', u'Days', u'Payed'],]
     ...: for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0]):
     ...:     t=zip(*(i[-1] for i in g))
     ...:     for i in t:
     ...:         lstB.append([k]+list(i))

#outputs:
In [587]: lstB
Out[587]: 
[['id', u'Work Load', u'Days', u'Payed'],
 [142L, 57.35, 84.0, 5684.0],
 [142L, 19.57, 44.0, 3944.0],
 [547L, 87.25, 98.0, 3247.0],
 [547L, 12.7, 128.0, 4712.0]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Allthough headers' order are not allways known, also not all data have values for one or more headers. e.g.: list can be: [[142L, u'Work Load', [57.35, 19.57]],
 [142L, u'Days', [84.0, 44.0]],
 [142L, u'Payed', [5684.0]],
 [547L, u'Work Load', [87.25, 12.7]],
 [547L, u'Days', [98.0, 128.0]],
 ], but empty data (i.e. 0 or '') is acceptable. I tried this but it didn't worked as expected.

Comment: @VasilisKasapidis then unutbu's answer might be better

Answer (score 1):

Using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

listA = [[142L, u'Work Load', [57.35, 19.57]],
[142L, u'Days', [84.0, 44.0]],
[142L, u'Payed', [5684.0, 3944.0]],
[547L, u'Work Load', [87.25, 12.70]],
[547L, u'Days', [98.0, 128.0]],
[547L, u'Payed', [3247.0, 4712.0]]]

dfA = pd.DataFrame(listA)
dfA.columns = ['id','field','data']

dfB = dfA.groupby('id').apply(
    lambda grp: pd.DataFrame(zip(*grp['data']), columns=grp['field']))
dfB.index = dfB.index.droplevel(-1)
print(dfB)
```

yields the DataFrame

```
field  Work Load  Days  Payed
id                           
142        57.35    84   5684
142        19.57    44   3944
547        87.25    98   3247
547        12.70   128   4712
```

Then you could write the DataFrame to a CSV using

```
dfB.to_csv('/tmp/test.csv', sep=',')
```

which would look like this:

```
id,Work Load,Days,Payed
142,57.35,84.0,5684.0
142,19.57,44.0,3944.0
547,87.25,98.0,3247.0
547,12.7,128.0,4712.0
```

Comment: How can i convert the dfB back to a list?

Comment: `dfB.to_records().tolist()`

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: managed to work it out otherwise using to_csv and streamIO. Bellow is my code.